Cannot use TikZ-FeynHand with `trig format=rad`
TikZ-FeynHand fails to draw propagators when trig format=rad. Is there a way to use TikZ-FeynHand while having trig format=rad globally?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynhand}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{trig format=rad}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynhand}
        \propag[pho] (0,0) to (2,0);
    \end{feynhand}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

/home/ulysses/test/test.tex:8: Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@x 
                           
l.8         \propag[pho] (0,0) to (2,0);
                                  


The pgf documentation says (at the end of section 94.3.5)

Warning: At the time of this writing, this feature is “experimental”. Please handle it with care: there may be path instructions or libraries in pgf which rely on trig format=deg. The intended usage of trig format=rad is for local scopes – and as option for data visualization.

so I'd say the answer to your question is No.

Do as suggested by the warning and only activate trig format=rad in scopes where you need it.
If you only need the trigonometric functions once or twice per scope, it may be easier to do the conversion on the fly using the r postfix operator, i.e. write sin(1r) instead of sin(1) and cos(pi r) instead of cos(pi). Do not do this when trig format=rad is active!
If you are really, really sure that it's only feynhand that has problems with this, you can reset the option to trig format=deg in that environment. I would strongly discourage this, though, as there are almost certainly other problems if you are using more pgf based libraries like pgfplots or TikZ.

